# if NSDictionary is reference type then why it is not propagate itself to subclasses?

Tags: swift

According to apple blog, they says: Copying a reference, on the other hand, implicitly creates a shared instance. After a copy, two variables then refer to a single instance of the data, so modifying data in the second variable also affects the original

```
 // Reference type example
 class C { var data: Int = -1 }
 var x = C()
 var y = x                          // x is copied to y
 x.data = 42                        // changes the instance referred to 
 by x (and y)
 println("\(x.data), \(y.data)")    // prints "42, 42"
```

Then i tried it with NSDictionary class. But it does not seen to work like plain class. So i do not can use NSDictionary class as a type like in example above ?

```
 var a = NSDictionary()
 var b = a
 a = ["a":"b"]
 b.object(forKey: "a") .   //nil
```

Comment: `var a = NSDictionary()` followed by `a = ["a":"b"]`, you are overriting `a`. Are you looking for this: https://pastebin.com/1VzdZN3S ?

Comment: `a = ["a":"b"]` points `a` to an entirely new Dictionary.  Try making `a` an `NSMutableDictionary` and then inserting a new key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 2nd test isn't valid. You assign an `NSDictionary` to `a`. Then you point `b` to that same dictionary. But then you assign a whole new Swift dictionary to `a`. This has no effect on `b`. `b` still points to the original `NSDictionary` it was assigned to. Reassigning `a` to something else will never change `b`.

Here's a better test.

```
var a = NSMutableDictionary()
b = a
a["a"] = "b"
b.object(forKey: "a") // "b"
```

Here, both `a` and `b` are pointing to the same `NSMutableDictionary`. When you update that dictionary via `a`, you will see the change in `b` as well since both variables point to the same dictionary.